# Using Jake Wharton's ViewPageIndicator

Tags: android, android-library, viewpagerindicator

I'm trying to use the ViewPageIndicator library in my class, but am running into difficulties.   I downloaded the library from Git, created a new Android project using the library code, and it is filled with errors.  I made sure that the support libraries for v4 and v13 are there, which cut down on the errors by quite a bit, but there are still hundreds of errors flagged by Eclipse.  Most of them are due to `@Override` which leads me to believe I'm missing a support library.  The installation instructions on the GitHub page are as vague as can be and just mentions adding it as a library to your project, nothing more.  So is there something that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@Overide` errors can be solved simply by doing the following:

1. Right click Project > Properties
2. Java Compilers > click 'Enable project specific settings' and set Compiler level to 1.6
3. Click 'Apply'

Comment: Wow, to think that I have been trying to figure this out for hours lol.  Thanks!

Comment: Another problem has come up in trying to get this set up.  Any idea why TitleProvider won't import?  Says that it can't be found, yet I'm able to `import com.viewpagerindicator.*;` just fine.

Comment: have you followed all the steps which described

Comment: There weren't any steps really except "Make sure to implement TitleProvider" yet I can't find that interface at all in the library.

Comment: `TitleProvider` was removed in the latest release since `PagerAdapter` now has a `getTitle(int)` method. I need to update the website...