# ViewPagerIndicator Dependencies Missing

Tags: android, eclipse, dependencies, viewpagerindicator

Using: Eclipse & ADT20

I am having issues using Jake Wharton's [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) in a new project.

After following the instructions on Jake's github page I receive an error in my application when adding the library. If I look in the Android Dependencies (located; Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries) there is a library.jar referenced but it has a red cross and says "missing".

On github page it says "A standalone JAR is not possible due to the theming capabilities offered by the indicator widgets." so why is my project trying to reference one?

I have tried removing the Android Dependencies and cleaned the project with to no avail. I've ran "Add Library Support" and "Fix Project Properties"

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The solution can be found here: [Using Jake Wharton's ViewPageIndicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271988/using-jake-whartons-viewpageindicator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new Android Library Project, copied over the files from ViewPagerIndicator's "library" subdirectory and then (to fix some problems with some Holo themes not being found) edited the project.properties to:

```
target=android-14
```

This last bit at least meant the library project would compile. I have no idea why it is initially set to level 4.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/project.properties

Comment: I followed you instructions and the library is now compiling. However importing (import com.viewpagerindicator.*;) the library into an Activity doesn't expose any methods. Were you able to actually use the library?

Comment: Are you sure you are adding the library project as a "library project" to your own android project?  All working fine for me.  Right-click on your own project > Properties > Android > Library > Add... > ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Yeah I've linked the Library to the Project as specified. Looking closer; the jar file generated that is generated is only 1KB! Maybe something is wrong with the compilation?

Comment: Ah after further investigation the issue was caused by the CCL being 1.7 instead of 1.6. see link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271988/using-jake-whartons-viewpageindicator) - Thanks Mark for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue

I removed my project from Eclipse and copied it beside library project

then add my project and library project to Eclipse again and in project.properties file of project replaced this

```
target=android-7
android.library.reference.1=../library
```

also changed target SDK of library to 7

really strange but worked